# Fatal error: Out of memory (in composer) during upgrade Magento2.2.1 to Magento 2.3 when run composer update command

Tags: magento-upgrade

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1045438464) (tried to allocate
>   16777216 bytes) in
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php
>   on line 220

I am using Siteground Hosting.
[image]

Comment: This one may help some of you facing the same problem https://litextension.com/blog/update-magento-using-composer/

Answer (score 0):

1- Locate your main php.ini file by executing `php --ini`
 You will find the path in

```
Loaded Configuration File:         PATH\TO\php.ini
```

2- update `memory_limit` to a higher value or -1 to maximum

3- save file and rerun your composer command again.

Second Option if you can't edit the main php.ini

You can use custom .ini file to run composer

```
php -n -c /PATH/TO/custom.ini composer.phar
```

and download `composer.phar` from getcomposer website

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the siteground support from your siteground account support  section as I had faced same issue and contacted the support they increase the PHP memory limit and issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

> Run this command
>
> > composer require -dmemory_limit=-1 magento/product-community-edition
> >     `your update version` --no-update